# Конструктор копирования в наследуемом классе

Tags: c++

Запутался с наследованием и конструкторами. Как я понимаю, что наследование конструкторов в с++ не происходит, кроме базового.Но вот попался пример ,где чтобы запретить копирование предлагают наследоваться от такого класса:

```
class NonCopyable
{
  public: 
    NonCopyable (const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable & operator = (const NonCopyable &) = delete;

  protected:
    NonCopyable () = default;
    ~NonCopyable () = default; /// Protected non-virtual destructor
};
```

```
class CantCopy : private NonCopyable
{};
```

И тогда копирование будет запрещено, но разве у нас должно происходить наследование этого конструктора, если он с параметром?

```
NonCopyable (const NonCopyable &) = delete;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наследование конструкторов в С++ может быть только явным. И конструктор по-умолчанию не исключение. В приведенном примере никакого наследования конструкторов не происходит. В данном случае компилятор создает для класса `CantCopy` конструктор по-умолчанию, в котором вызывается конструктор по-умолчанию базовых подъобъектов и полей. Такой конструктор без проблем корректно создается. А вот при попытке аналогичным образом сгенерировать конструктор копирования компилятор постигнет фиаско, так как конструктор копирования базового класса отмечен как запрещенный.

Comment: @user7860670 Т.е. если мы запрещаем какие-нибудь конструкторы в базовом классе ,то в наследуемом они тоже будут всегда запрещены? Но почему тогда работает CantCopy(const CantCopy&):NonCopyable(){ }

Comment: @Вячеслав *"если мы запрещаем какие-нибудь конструкторы в базовом классе ,то в наследуемом они тоже будут всегда запрещены"* В общем случае нет. Тут дело в том, что сгенерированный автоматически конструктор копирования для `CantCopy` попытался бы вызвать удаленный конструктор копирования `NonCopyable`, так что генерация не происходит. А в вашем примере удаленный конструктор не используется, поэтому все работает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Правильно ли я понимаю, что если явно его не писать, то он выглядит так :

CantCopy(const CantCopy&): NonCopyable (const NonCopyable &)

Comment: @Вячеслав Ну не совсем так, но смысл правильный. Скорее как-то так: `CantCopy(const CantCopy &x) : NonCopyable(static_cast<const NonCopyable &>(x)) {}`

Comment: @Вячеслав Самостоятельно компилятор может создавать только особые конструкторы - конструктор по-умолчанию, копирующий и перемещающий. И еще соотв. операторы и деструктор. Если же самостоятельно определить копирующий конструктор, то компилятор не будет пытаться его генерировать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо за помощь! А Вы бы не посоветовали книги, в которых можно почитать о таких вещах?

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо !

Comment: @Вячеслав Вот тут есть подборка книг: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2752075

Comment: @Вячеслав Можно почитать стандарт, раздел Special member functions

Comment: @user7860670  благодарю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat благодарю